# How to check if pip is already installed on a Mac

Tags: pip

What command do I write in the terminal to check if pip is installed on my MacBook?  I can't find any Mac specific commands online to check.  I thought I already had it installed, but I'm not sure now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running

```
$ pip -V
```

If it prints information about pip, it's installed.
If not, either it's not installed, or your environment variables are not set up properly.
For the latter, I can't tell you how to fix unless I know how you tried installing it.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what WindowsNT wrote, it might be `pip3 -V` instead of just `pip -V` if you are using Python 3.